# i use kivy module on python and its unable to open a window, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to use `kivy` for the first time on Python 3.7.9 and I wrote this simple code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="test112")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

The output is:

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\shavi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\shavi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This runs fine. You are missing some dependencies.

Install these dependencies and try again:

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew; 

python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
```